# Holding references of view models

Tags: android, mvvm

I have been using MVVM architecture in my project. Now there came a point where my view model holds all the references to the variables that I need for a subsequent network call, is it okay to hold reference to that view model, that has transient callback, in state manager so that i can use those variables to feed my n/w request post params? Is there any potential downfall to this approach?